# how to refer to current p tag in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have tried 
in html as

```
 <?php while (have_posts()) :the_post(); ?>
  <div class="product-content">
   <?php if ($len > 122): ?>
   <?php echo $sub ."........"; ?>
   <p class="invisible"><?php echo $cont; ?> </p>
   <?php else: ?>
   <?php echo $sub ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
```

in jquery as

```
$(".product-content").click(function(){
    var t= $(this p).text();
```

or

```
$(".product-content").click(function(){
    var t= $(this ".invisible").text();
```

Comment: I would recommend indenting the PHP code better,

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = $(this).find('p').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just call it directly?

```
$('.product-content').click(function(){ 
    $('.invisible').text();
});
```

Comment: Because not searching the whole DOM is a lot faster...?

Answer (score 1):

try to use as follows:

```
$(this).children("p.invisible").text()
```